# Possible to set the ARM MMU to allow code execution, but not allow reading

Tags: arm, mmu

I'd like to know if it's possible to set permissions on a page table entry for the ARM7 (Cortex A8 specifically) MMU such that code execution from the page is allowed, but reads are not allowed.

If the permissions are orthogonal you might think that if XN (execute never) is not set, that execution would be allowed regardless of if reading is allowed.

Of course, some ARM code reads from itself as it's executing (to get literals that are stored just beyond the end of the function for example), that code would be unlikely to work.

If the code you were trying to execute *didn't* do any reads from itself (more specifically, from the page with reading disabled), would the code execute as expected or would you get a data abort (or other) exception?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. The processor has to read the code section in order to fetch the instructions that are to be executed. How could you disable read-permission and still have the processor executing that code (i.e., how else would it "get inside" the CPU)?

Comment: If the system used a hardvard architecture (separate pathways for code and data), which I believe ARM does, then it could certainly be possible that accessing memory as the processor executes would use different permissions than accessing memory for data access.  Advancing, updating PC could have different semantics than a LDR, for example.

Comment: Yes, but after the PC is incremented, the next instruction still needs to be fetched (i.e., the memory address pointed by the PC needs to be read from).

Comment: Agreed. I'm simply wondering if the processor (which knows why it's doing one read vs. the other), via the MMU, could allow the read to fetch the instruction, but not allow any other data access to that page.  In a way it's similar to how XN is implemented. The instruction is fetched, like any other read, but then it's executed. The MMU must know if the intent is to execute the instruction or it could never generate an exception when XN is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem the answer is *no*.

From *ARM® Architecture Reference Manual ARMv7-A and ARMv7-R edition* section B3.7.2

> A processor can
>   execute instructions from a memory region only if the access permissions for its current state permit read access, and the XN bit is set to 0.